# how can I calculate month count between two dates

Tags: php, datetime, datediff

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

[image]

```
$begintime=strtotime("2012-12-19");
$endtime=strtotime("2013-02-22");
```

The result should be;

```
array(
array('text'=>'12/2012','days'=>13),
array('text'=>'01/2013','days'=>31)
array('text'=>'02/2013','days'=>22)
)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're looking for. Can you clarify?

Comment: Have you looked into [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: take a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

Comment: I updated question. I want to result as array

Comment: The question should be improved.

Comment: @Sithu If the begin day not first day, It should be remaining day count in month. If the begin day is first day, It should be elapsed day count in month.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233605/elegant-way-to-get-the-count-of-months-between-two-dates loook atr this

Comment: It starts 00:00 am ;) I added screenshot

Comment: What version of PHP is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For getting the days, try this:

```
$begintime = '2012-12-19';
$endtime = '2013-02-22';
$bd = new DateTime($begintime);
$ed = new DateTime($endtime);

$c = $bd->format('t') - $bd->format('d') + 1;
$pass = false;

while($bd->format('Y') < $ed->format('Y')
        || $bd->format('n') < $ed->format('n')) {
    $bd->modify("+1 month");
    echo $c." ";
    $c = $bd->format('t');
    $pass = true;
}
$c = $ed->format('d');
if(!$pass)
    $c -= $bd->format('d') - 1;
echo $c;
```

See http://ideone.com/07wqkp

`$bd->format('t')` gives the maximum number of days in a month.

ideone uses PHP 5.2.11. I suppose with PHP 5.4 you could use

```
$bd->add(new DateInterval("P1M"));
```

instead of `$bd->modify("+1 month");`.

**EDIT:** Fixed bug when starting and ending in the same month and year.

**EDIT:** <strike>Reverted to explicit comparisons.</strike> On second thought, it's better without the if/else.

Comment: +1 for `$bd->add(new DateInterval("P1M"));` it will work.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to work it in Object-oriented approach.

```
$begintime = new DateTime('2012-12-19'); // always use single quote whenever possible
$endtime = new DateTime('2013-01-22');
$time_interval = $endtime->diff($begintime); // in DateInterval object format

echo 'the time interval will be: ' . $time_interval->format('%d') . ' days';
```

For the conversion to Array format you suggested, please work it on your own. ( not the focus of the question, I think )

Comment: Can you look at my result array. Your result not correct

Comment: as said in question, conversion to Array is not the focus. We can't teach you every tiny bit.