# How to find month difference between today and other date from database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have today date stored in variable
       $today=date("Y-m-d");
and other variable which is date fetched from mysql database.
      $date2=(row['date2']);

I have tried with date_diff:

```
$diff=$today-$date2;
```

But $today is string and i cant find out a solution.I have tried with
     $today=newDateTime (date("Y-m-d"));
And get an error: Object Of Class DateTime Could Not Be Converted To Int

Should mention that after i get the month i need to store them in a variable and multiply with other variable.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: "Month difference" can you give examples i can think of several ways depending on the value you are after

Comment: There is one other way described here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233605/elegant-way-to-get-the-count-of-months-between-two-dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im guessing you want this:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, CURDATE(), DB_FIELD)
```

example

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, CURDATE(), '2012-01-01')
```

returns **-12**, as that date was 12 months ago

Manual page: [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

Comment: Thank you dagon, you make my day :)

Answer (score 0):

why not use `CURDATE()`? the query should look like this

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date2)
```

- [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)
- [CURDATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)

Comment: that was my first idea to, but 'month difference' is another story as that will return days

Comment: me? 'green' but i suspect the OP has other ideas :-)

Comment: Thank you JW. CURDATE() was the perfect solution.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php
     $date1 = date(strtotime('2013-01-23'));
     $date2 = date(strtotime('2013-05-31'));
     $difference = $date2 - $date1;
     $months = floor($difference / 86400 / 30 );
     echo $months;
?>
```