# Get total month count between 2 dates inclusive

Tags: php, date

I need help to get month count between 2 dates:

```
$date1 = "2013-01-15";
$date2 = "2013-04-15";
```

I need to get the result of: `4`, which are `Jan`, `Feb`, `Mar`, and `Apr` from the above variables.

Is there a simple way to get the result instead by exploding those dates?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Elegant way to get the count of months between two dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233605/elegant-way-to-get-the-count-of-months-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if running php >= 5.3 try this:

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2013-01-15");
$date2 = new DateTime("2013-04-15");
var_dump($date1->diff($date2)->m + 1); // int(4)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2013-01-15');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2013-04-15');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%M%');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

 $d1 = new DateTime('2013-01-15');
 $d2 = new DateTime('2013-04-15');

$interval = $d2->diff($d1);

$interval = ($interval->format('%m months')) +1;
```

?>

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php