# Comparing day and month in php

Tags: php, date, date-comparison

Good evening!

Problem: 
The problem is to compare 2 dates in PHP.
I want to only compare day and month, excluding the year.
I want the code to first check the month, if the month is same or less than current month. If it's true, move on to check the day. If the day is equal to, or less than current day, execute a custom code.

What I've tried:
Here is where I got so far -

```
<?php
$oldDate = "26/02/1815";
$latestDate = explode("/", $oldDate);
$year = $latestDate[2];
$month = $latestDate[1];
$day = $latestDate[0];

$newDate = $month.'/'.$day.'/'.$year;
$nowDate = date('m/d/Y');

$nownowDate = explode("/", $nowDate);
$nowYear = $nownowDate[2];
$nowMonth = $nownowDate[0];
$nowDay = $nownowDate[1];

if ($nowMonth <= $month) {
    if ($nowDay <= $day) {
        echo<<<NEXTDATE
        <li class="next"><?php echo link_to_next_item_show(); ?></li> //This is the custom code
NEXTDATE;
    } 
} 
?>
```

I feel that there is something wrong with my IFs statement.

Comment: Are you getting any form of error? I can't say I am familiar with the <<< syntax, but your if statements look OK.

Comment: `I feel that there is something wrong with my IFs statement.` Why? You need to describe the actual problem, not just state that you have a vague feeling.

Comment: @developerwjk The problem is: in the custom code, there is a block of html + php code that needed to be echoed once the condition is true, but I can't get the custom code to display, as if something's wrong with the IF statement. I can't figure it out.

Comment: @CT14.IT it's called heredoc http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: In the example you've provided, the if statements are fine. If I change oldDate to e.g. "26/04/2015" I get the "Custom code" output. I do not think anyone here can help until we actually see the actual code that's the problem.

Comment: @CT14.IT I've added the custom code. I think there's a problem validating the day. I'm trying here as well.

Answer (score 2):

From:
[Elegant way to get the count of months between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233605/elegant-way-to-get-the-count-of-months-between-two-dates)

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'); 
$d1 = new DateTime("1815-02-26", $timezone);
$d2 = new DateTime("2015-01-01", $timezone);

var_dump($d1->diff($d2)->m); // int(4)
var_dump($d1->diff($d2)->d); // int(4)

if(($d1->diff($d2)->m) && ($d1->diff($d2)->d)){
   echo "run code here";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put `<?php` tags inside a [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). So, instead of using a heredoc you could do:

```
echo '<li class="next">' . link_to_next_item_show() . '</li>';
```

Comment: This is useful! if only I can upvote it :) thanks @developerwjk

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for trying your best at solving this problem. Maybe I didn't make it clear, that's why some of you were struggling, trying to understand what I was talking about.

I've tried to solve this problem using switch, so here is the answer that works for me.

```
<?php 

$oldDate = metadata('item', array('Dublin Core', 'Date')); 
$latestDate = explode("/", $oldDate);
$year = $latestDate[2];
$month = $latestDate[1];
$day = $latestDate[0];

$newDate = $month.'/'.$day.'/'.$year;
$nowDate = date('m/d/Y');

$nownowDate = explode("/", $nowDate);
$nowYear = $nownowDate[2];
$nowMonth = $nownowDate[0];
$nowDay = $nownowDate[1];

switch (true):

  case ($month == $nowMonth):
    if ($day < $nowDay) {
      echo '<li class="next">' . link_to_next_item_show() . '</li>';
    } else {
      echo " ";
    }
    break;

  case ($month < $nowMonth):
    echo '<li class="next">' . link_to_next_item_show() . '</li>';
    break;

  case ($month > $nowMonth):
    echo " "; 
    break;
  default :
    echo " ";
    break;
endswitch;

?>
```

Thank you to @developerwjk for the correction on using php tag inside heredoc. Now I know what's wrong with the code. I'm providing this as an answer so that other people will benefit from this, if they are trying to compare between two dates (comparing between day and month only, regardless of its year). Hope this is useful for others in the future.