# Difference between 2 dates in months Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have a question here. I need to get the difference betweeen 2 dates in months by using Yii2. I know that I should use `diff` and `format it in months`, but it's not working. Could someone help me to solve the problem?

Here is my line that I need to count the difference in months:

```
$holidays = 'floor(datediff(curdate(), employment_date))';
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

Comment: Is it possible to do it in 1 or 2 lines? I don't want to write 20 lines of code just to do the difference in months

Comment: I dont think so , there was a extension in yii 1 try to find extension in yii2 , or write it once and use it many times.

Comment: [You can write four lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233605/elegant-way-to-get-the-count-of-months-between-two-dates)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elegant way to get the count of months between two dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233605/elegant-way-to-get-the-count-of-months-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using mysql, you can use [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff):

```
$holidays = '(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, employment_date, curdate()))';
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already [an good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233605/elegant-way-to-get-the-count-of-months-between-two-dates) by @Vincent Savard. Here it is in two lines:

```
$diff = (new DateTime($employment_date))->diff(new DateTime());
$holidays = $diff->m + $diff->y*12;
```