# How to get list all months data between two dates php

Tags: php

How to find number of months between two dates using PHP?
and provide dates also like below

```
$fromdate = 12-01-2018
$todate = 18-04-2018
```

i want output per month like

```
12-01-2018 - 12-02-2018
12-02-2018 - 12-03-2018
12-03-2018 - 12-04-2018
12-04-2018 - 18-04-2018
```

i tried

```
    $datetime1 = new DateTime("2010-06-20");

    $datetime2 = new DateTime("2011-06-22");

    $difference = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

    echo 'Difference: '.$difference->y.' years, '
        .$difference->m.' months, '
        .$difference->d.' days<br>';

    print_r($difference);
```

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elegant way to get the count of months between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233605/elegant-way-to-get-the-count-of-months-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this code. It increments `$start` (=`$fromdate`) by a month until it is equal to or later than `$end` (=`$todate`).

```
$fromdate = '12-01-2018';
$todate = '18-04-2018';

$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $fromdate);
$end = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $todate);

do {
    echo $start->format('d-m-Y') . ' - ';
    $start->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
    if ($start >= $end) {
        echo $end->format('d-m-Y') . "\n";
        break;
    }
    echo $start->format('d-m-Y') . "\n";
} while (true)
```

Output:

```
12-01-2018 - 12-02-2018
12-02-2018 - 12-03-2018
12-03-2018 - 12-04-2018
12-04-2018 - 18-04-2018
```